# How can i implement React Native Track Player on Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, expo, avaudioplayer

Is there a guide to follow to implement React Native Track Player on Expo.

I've tried and tried but it keeps giving the error
`cannot read property capability of null trackplayer`

I made a little research and I saw that you have to invoke the Trackplayer setup service just after registering the root component.

But with Expo SDK > 49.
There isn't a root component because, while implementing the expo router, you have to change the main entry to expo-router.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to use this on Expo Go, I don't think it's possible. You'll have to use expo's development build. More at https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-react-native-track-player/62714/8